# Can't access to elements of a hash after getting them from a csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have a cvs and I want to access the values. If I do this:

```
    require 'csv'   
    CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true) do |row|
      new_row = row.to_hash
      puts "#{new_row}"
    end
```

This is the result -> `{"user_id"=>"111", "sport"=>"aaa"}`

But if I do this nothing gets printed

```
    require 'csv'   
    CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true) do |row|
      new_row = row.to_hash
      puts "#{new_row["user_id"]}"
    end
```

Why is this? How can I get the info?

Comment: These 2 blocks of code are identical. Should there be a variance between them?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes, sorry! I updated the question.

Comment: Small tip, you don't need to use string interpolation to print a variable that is not a string.

Comment: It would be simpler to write `CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true) { |row| puts row[:user_id] }`.

Comment: Wow I didn't realize the parser would allow double quoted hash keys inside a double quoted interpolation. I thought they had to be single inside, but that does work

Answer (score 0):

Try using a symbol to find the key instead of a string

```
require 'csv'   
  CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true) do |row|
  new_row = row.to_hash
  puts new_row[:user_id]
end
```

Comment: Hey! I tried `new_row[:user_id]` but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you print out `new_row.class` and see if its a hash

Comment: If you're sure its a hash then the issue might be that the CSV encoding is off and the key `user_id` has a hidden character in it that you cant see by just printing out the hash. You can test this by seeing if `new_row.keys.first.to_s == 'user_id'`

Comment: `new_row.class` is a Hash and `new_row.keys.first.to_s == 'user_id'` is false. ` new_row.keys.first.class` is a String. Doing `row[0]` work tho.

Comment: It should be a string. You should compare it to the string 'user_id' because if the key in the hash has a hidden character like 'user_id?' where ? is an invisible character then it will print false. This would mean you have an encoding issue.